# Get only text (without latex tag) from a latex command

Tags: macros, text

I need to get only the ascii text that a command print without latex formating (and also without linebreak).

I need it to automatically generate the pdf document name in `\hypersetup{pdftitle={<name of document>}}`

In some cases, I can define the title as `\title{My \texttt{run.py} script}` but, if I try to put `\hypersetup{pdftitle={\theauthor}}` (`\theauthor` came frome `titling` package).

That’s why I need to only extract text from the `\theauthor` command.

Comment: This question is very unclear to me. If you define something like `\newcommand\fauve{My name is fauve}`, then you can put `\fauve` in lots of places: `\documentclass{article} \newcommand\fauve{My name is fauve} \usepackage{hyperref} \hypersetup{pdfauthor=\fauve} \begin{document} \verb+\fauve+: \fauve \end{document}`....

Comment: Yes, but if i defined `\newcommand\fauve{The \textbb{Greath} \tiny{and} \emph{popular} \bsc{Fauve}}` I can’t put the `\fauve` command on `pdfauthor` field like `\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\fauve}`. It will fail.
I need to extract only the text that the `\fauve` command print. I need to only get “The Greath and popular Fauve”, without TeX macros.

Comment: There is a macro called `\texorpdfstring{<TeX>}{<PDF>}` from `hyperref`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I find where I had a mistake, I put the pdf definitions before the `\title` and `\author` declarations.

This is the good way to obtain automatic pdf adaptation (also if it contain LaTeX tag):

```
\title{My \textbf{Great} title\\ and subtitle}
\author{\textbsc{ME}}
\date{\today}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                       PDF specificity                           %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
  \hypersetup{
    pdftitle={\@title},
    pdfauthor={\@author}
  }
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\fauve{My \texorpdfstring{\textbf{name}}{name} is fauve} 
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\fauve}
\begin{document}
\verb+\fauve+: \fauve                                                   
\end{document}
```

Comment: It’s a begining of a solution but it isn’t satisfying. In some cases, the `\title` or the `\name` is generated by another commands… that’s why I realy need to extract text.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your comments are too vague to be of much help to me. What other 'commands'? Generate the command properly would be my advice. That's what `\texorpdfstring` is *specifically* designed to do. If something is generating `foo \textbf{bar} baz`, why can't it generate `foo \texorpdfstring{\textbf{bar}}{bar} baz`? Or, if you want to 'extract' text, preprocess it with a language that is designed to manipulate text in that way and use TeX for the typesetting.

Comment: This kind of question would benefit from being edited to include a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).